# How do I enable apturl in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, apturl

If I click on an apt:// link in Firefox I just get 'The address wasn't understood'.
apturl is installed and I've tried adding the apt protocol (network.protocol-handler.expose.apt) in Firefox and adding entries into the gconf database with gconftool but it still doesn't work. I have managed to get Firefox to prompt for an application but you can't select one because permission is denied to all the system files.